# I am not able to open XAMPP sites after Latest Windows 10 Update

Tags: windows, windows-10, mysql, xampp

I have recently upgraded to Windows 10 Version 1809. But after upgrade I am not able to access sites from my portable xampp. I tried to do fresh install of xampp but still it didn't worked. Apache and MySql process are running but I am not able to open any xampp site. Even Phpmyadmin is not opening.
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

It Says

This site can’t be reached
The connection was reset.

Comment: what error dose browser is displaying when you close all service of xampp ?

Comment: I have reinstalled the windows and problem fixed.